# Can't erase 2nd hard drive from recovery

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility

I have a 2012 13" Macbook pro, running macOS Sierra. I have 2 hard drive set up, in the optical bay I have ssd with all system operation files. I'm trying to install a new hdd in normal hard drive slot, but for whatever reason can't erase it. I have tried plugging it externally, after I initialize it I can transfer files to it. Then I put it in hard drive slot and try to partition it but get an error. I have tried erasing disk in recovery mode and/or unmounting drive with terminal commands but I eventually get the same result
[image]

[image]

[image]

I usually can figure out all that stuff, and it is not the first time I am installing new hard drive, but I can't figure it out for some reason

Progress update.
Plugged disk externally, erased in in recovery mode. Plugged disk internally, gettin the same error. Unmounted through terminal commands.

Used `sudo diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ MacintoshHD disk2` to try and wipe disk completely.
Got
`Error: -69825: Wiping volume data to prevent future accidental probing failed`

Progress update.
The issue has to be with the hard drive cable itself. Will update the question once I have a new cable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've put in a new hard drive cable, and all the issues are fixed